# interp command in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I'm learning Tcl and now I'm blocked on tcl command **interp**

I read that this command is used for create and manipulate interpreters, but what are interpreters and when they are used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tcl interpreters are execution contexts. Each interpreter has it's own namespaces, commands and global variables; they do not share anything (except for a few things, such as the current working directory, that are process-global). Interpreters are created as either ordinary ones (with a full set of built-in Tcl commands) or as *safe* interpreters, where no commands are exposed that can adversely affect the outside world.

In general, interpreters are isolated from each other (to the point where the isolation is a security feature) but it is possible to do a few things that cross between them: the main ones are that a parent interpreter can tell one of its child interpreters to evaluate a script for it and return the result, and a parent interpreter can put an *alias command* in a child that, when called, will invoke a (nominated) command in the parent passing over the parents. The result of this is that you can treat the parent-child relationship as being a bit like the relationship between an OS kernel and a user process, with the alias command being like a system call. (It isn't a perfect analogy, so don't think too hard about it.)

```
set foo [interp create -safe]
proc sayhelloto {who} {
    puts "Hello, $who!"
}
interp alias $foo hello {} sayhelloto

interp eval $foo {
    hello "World"
    hello "ThaDome23"
    exec echo rm -rf evilstuff
}
# Hello, World!
# Hello, ThaDome23!
# error: no such command 'exec'
```

So, you use additional interpreters whenever you want an independent execution context. They are heavyweight so you don't want to create them too often, but they're hugely cheaper than another process.

Finally, every interpreter is bound to the thread that creates it. Different threads *always* use independent interps.